# results on where condition on same column and with another column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like below

```
bundle_id  asset_id  price_id
1           2        1
1           1        1
1           4        1
2           2        1
2           3        1
3           2        1
3           1        1
```

and i need to get the results of `bundle_id` = 1 using `AND` operation on same column `asset_id` .

I was trying the below queries none of them worked.

```
SELECT bundle_id
FROM mac.bundle_prices
WHERE asset_id =2 and asset_id=1 and asset_id =4 and  price_id =1 
GROUP BY bundle_id

SELECT bundle_id
FROM mac.bundle_prices
WHERE asset_id IN ('2', '1','4') and  price_id =1 
GROUP BY bundle_id
```

any suggestions, please!

Comment: Your first query always give you empty result. but what is the issue with second query?

Comment: `asset_id =2 and asset_id=1 and asset_id =4` something can't be all of these three at once :)

Comment: @B.Desai: second query gives all three bundle_id .which I don't want? I want to get the correct bundle_id which has the exact combination of asset_id

Comment: What is the expected resultset?  What do you mean by 'need to get the results of bundle_id = 1' ? Use bundle_id in where clause if you need results for bundle_id=1. What is the condition for selecting results for bundle_id=1 if not bundle_id itself?

Answer (score 0):

you could use having for check that all the asset_id  match

```
select bundle_id
from  mac.bundle_prices 
WHERE asset_id IN (2, 1,4)
group by bundle_id
having count(distinct asset_id) = 3
```

I asssumed  that asset_id type is  number

using asset_id   if you want bundle_id 2  you should use

```
select bundle_id
from  mac.bundle_prices 
WHERE asset_id IN (2, 3)
group by bundle_id
having count(distinct asset_id) = 2
```

Comment: You mentioned having count . is it not possible without that? as i want to use the same query to get all other bundle_id 's for different where asset_id combination

Comment: based on asset_id  you must know the number of these for be sure that all match  ..Moreover, you must also indicate the elements of the IN clause  .. then you should  know this count value

Comment: Then if I want to get the bundle_id =2 your query does not work right? I just tried with the below query for bundle_id 2 `select bundle_id
from  mac.bundle_prices 
WHERE asset_id IN (2, 3)
group by bundle_id
having count(distinct asset_id) = 3`  . This did not work

Comment: @06011991 what exactly you want. We cant understand your logic. Give more explanation

Comment: You are asking for bundle_id = 1   ..  .. not for bundle_id = 2 .. anyway answer  updated  for bundel_id 2 too

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sql

```
SELECT bundle_id
FROM mac.bundle_prices
WHERE asset_id IN ('2', '1','4') and  price_id =1 
GROUP BY asset_id
```

Comment: Are you sure @06011991 ? check this screenshot http://prntscr.com/gfsedj

Comment: `Error Code: 1055. Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'mac.bundle_prices.bundle_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by` this is what i got

Answer (score 0):

From your comments I think you need bundle_id where its same as asset_id. Try below query

```
SELECT bundle_id
FROM mac.bundle_prices
WHERE asset_id IN (2, 1,4) and  price_id =1 AND asset_id = bundle_id
GROUP BY bundle_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The English language is a mess.  In English, "and" can mean "or".  But in any mathematical or computer arena, it does *not*.

`asset_id IN (2, 1, 4)` means `asset_id = 2 OR asset_id = 1 OR asset_id = 4`, *not* `asset_id = 2 and asset_id = 1 and asset_id = 4`.  Think about it.  `asset_id` has only one value; it cannot be `=2` *and* `=1` simultaneously.  But it can be "2" *or* "1".

On the other hand, perhaps you are asking "Are there 3 rows with different `asset_id` values?  Specifically, with 2,1,4."

So, we need to find all the rows with `price_id =1`, then see what `asset_id` values were found.  There are two ways...

```
SELECT bundle_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(asset_id ORDER BY asset_id) AS list
    FROM bundle_prices
    WHERE price_id = 1
    GROUP BY bundle_id
    HAVING list = "1,2,4";  -- (this order matters)
```

But this has a potential flaw.  What if there were a 4th row, with `asset_id = 7`?  That's easy to fix:

```
SELECT bundle_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(asset_id ORDER BY asset_id) AS list
    FROM bundle_prices
    WHERE price_id = 1
      AND asset_id IN (2,1,4)  -- (this order does not matter)
    GROUP BY bundle_id
    HAVING list = "1,2,4";
```

The other approach also uses `HAVING`, but in a different way:

```
SELECT bundle_id
    FROM bundle_prices
    WHERE price_id = 1
      AND asset_id IN (2,1,4)
    GROUP BY bundle_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 3  -- exactly all 3 values
```

This technique has the advantage of answering "Which bundle_id has at least 2 of (2,1,4)" by changing the last line to `HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2`.